# WSO2 ESB read from a file

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to perform below two task.
First read the content of a file and append those content to response message of service using  WSO2 ESB. 
Second - I need to read a file from a source directory without moving or deleting that file from source directory. 
Can anybody suggest possible way to perform above operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created class mediator to do on demand read from a file and its successfully working.
First create a class mediator project - a java class that reads the file content and add those to synapse-config body.
Put that jar file in ESB_HOME/repository/component/lib
restart server and now that class will be available in ESB. :)
Below are the reference tutorials.

http://rajikak.blogspot.in/2010/03/writing-class-mediator-for-wso2-esb-300.html
http://www.nuwanbando.com/2013/06/reading-an-xml-file-into-wso2-esb-transform-it-and-expose-it-as-an-api/#more-1009

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Places+for+Putting+Custom+Mediators

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VFS](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/VFS+Transport) transport?

And

the sample http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838852

Comment: But in VFS transport we have only two option for ActionAfterProcess, that is MOVE or DELETE and default is DELETE. But i don't want to move or delete the file from source directory. My requirement is to retain the file in source directory.

Comment: @Ratha won't it make the reply file processed by the vfs transport again?

Comment: i tried but it couldn't work for me. below are my vfs parameters <parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI">vfs:ftp://admin:admin@localhost/filesrc?vfs.passive=true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">Move</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">2</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:ftp://admin:admin@localhost/filesrc?vfs.passive=true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:ftp://admin:admin@localhost/afterfailure?vfs.passive=true</parameter>

Comment: Another thing is my requirement is not polling. I need to read the file content as per the request. My proxy service transport protocol is http.

Comment: @Mari_Yaguchi yes it will make reply file processed by the vfs transport

Comment: @vashishth so have you solved your problem? if so, can u share the solution here?

Comment: @Mari_Yaguchi yes i have solved the problem. As i have posted the links above i have used to solve my problem. I have followed the same steps as described in "nuwanbaondo" blog and it is working very fine for me.